# Too many open files in system while not actually opening any files

Tags: c, macos, file-descriptor

I am developing a backup utility and I am getting the error:

> Too many open files in system

after it runs for a while. The error is returned by `stat()`.

Since I am not actually opening any files (`fopen()`), my question is if any of the following functions (which I am using) take up a file descriptor, and if so, what can I do to release it?

- `getwd()`
- `chdir()`
- `mkdir()`
- `stat()`
- `time()`

Comment: Is your program using opendir() ?

Comment: Nope, just the functions I listed along with `system()` to launch the `cp` command.

Comment: What is "launch the cp command" ? If you invoke cp via system() or popen(), that will cost you a few file descriptors, too.

Comment: But since I am copying the files sequentially, shouldn't that be a non issue?

Comment: Apperently it is an issue. Please note that there is a system-wide limit on the number of open files. If your "utility" spawns a lot of child-processes this limit could be easily hit (and it can hit *at any moment* where a file descriptor needs to be allocated). But since you don't show us any actual code, we can only guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions you listed are safe; none of them return anything that you could "close".

To find out more, run the command `lsof -p` + PID of your backup process. That will give you a list of files which the process has opened which in turn will give you an idea what is going on.

See: [`lsof` manual page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/lsof/).

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try today and get back with the results